# ¿Cómo puedo separar un string parcialmente?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando tratar un dataset en el que tengo una columna de los MB que dispone un cliente. Ejemplo cliente 1 tiene contratados 600MB, cliente 2 900MB. Quiero únicamente el número, sin el MB. He probado con split pero no obtengo nada más que fallos. lo tengo en una columna de un datframe.

¿Podéis ayudarme con ello?

Gracias

```
vel_conexion_= {'MB':['600MB', '500MB','800MB']}
df=pd.DataFrame(vel_conexion_)
df
```

Comment: Con rebanado de listas: `'600MB'[:-2]`

Comment: ¿Como puedo aplicarlo a un dataframe?

Comment: Reformula la pregunta mostrando el problema con el dataframe,

Comment: buenas! ya está reformulada Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar uno de los siguientes dos metodos:

```
lista=['600MB', '500MB', '800MB']

# Metodo 1: Elimina las letras 'MB'
nuevaLista=[e.lower().replace('mb','') for e in lista]

# Metodo 2: Elimina los ultimos dos caracteres
nuevaLista=[e[:-2] for e in lista]

vel_conexion_= {'MB':nuevaLista}
df=pd.DataFrame(vel_conexion_)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

A un dataframe pandas le puedes aplicar una función a todos los elementos de una columna, a través del método `.apply()`

En este caso la función que quieres aplicar es una que se quede con los primeros caracteres descartando los dos últimos. Esta función es tan simple que se puede escribir con una lambda así: `lambda x: x[:-2]`.

Por tanto tu problema se resolvería con una línea:

```
df.MB = df.MB.apply(lambda x: x[:-2])
```